# Laravel-Websockets, Nginx, Docker, Apache Mesos & more in this stack - 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, websocket

When we setup laravel-websockets locally in docker, everything worked wonderfully; however, when it all got pushed to prod, problems arose.  Consequently, we have to split up our main site into one server and the websocket server into a different server.  All of these sites are on a corporate internal network and do not use SSL.

So, the main application is Laravel 6 running on Centos, Apache 2.4, and PHP 7.3.  It can connect to the websocket server but anytime laravel broadcasts an event we get a 404 error for this endpoint:

`apps/XXXXXX/events?auth_key=XXXXXXX&auth_signature=XXXXXXX&auth_timestamp=XXXX&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=XXXXX`

The websocket server is Centos, PHP 7.3, Nginx 1.8 setup as a reverse proxy using spaties / beyondcodes example conf file.

```
map $http_upgrade $type {
  default "web";
  websocket "ws";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXXXXXXXX;
    root /opt/rh/rh-nginx18/root/usr/share/nginx/www/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files /nonexistent @$type;
    }

    location @web {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

      location @ws {
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:6001;
        proxy_set_header Host  $host;
        proxy_read_timeout     60;
        proxy_connect_timeout  60;
        proxy_redirect         off;

        # Allow the use of websockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

My whole team is new to nginx so we figure there is probably an issue there or something else that we have setup incorrectly.  We know our events and broadcasting within the main laravel app is correct, because it worked when it was all running on a single Apache cluster.  Our issue was, that corporate would not open a port in the firewall other than 80 and 443.  We are opting to split traffic across 80 with nginx as per beyondcode's documentation.

Any thoughts on this?  We are at a loss.  Thank you all!

Edit:

I should add we are using Laravel Echo with Pusher.JS for the front end:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    wsPort: 80,
    disableStats: true
});
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with most of these things, but reading your description doesn't help much in understanding what the actual problem is. To debug problems like this you should try to break it up into small, debuggable pieces, until you get to a point that does work. From there, try to find out step by step what goes wrong. This may sound like shitty advice, but the reason I'm saying it is because there's too much information here.

Comment: So to take a step back: the app endpoint that 404's, is it part of the laravel application or is some other application? Does the caller actual use the correct domain name or IP?. Can you reach the URL by using CURL from the local machine?

Comment: @vrijdenker As stated in the post, the JS from laravel-echo can connect to the websocket via port 80.  When we watch the log, it shows a successful subscription to the channel and if you leave, it shows it unsubscribed.  The problem comes when you try to broadcast an event from the application server running the Laravel app.When that event occurs, you get a 404 for the endpoint.  That is not an endpoint that we define.  It is something internal to laravel-websockets or laravel-echo.  As you stated, we broke this down a bunch.  The best guess is an nginx misconfig for routing.